# How to clear iOS LocationUsage preference from device for testing purposes?

Tags: ios

I have an iOS application that requests the user to allow or deny location access for the application.

From what I have read online, these preferences reset automatically every 24 hours. And an alternative would be to test on multiple devices.

Is there any way to clear these preferences manually before I re-run the application in the simulator?

Answer (score 0):

You can reset your location preferences, by following below steps:

1) From your *Home screen*, go to *Settings > General > Reset*

2) Select *Reset Location & Privacy*

**Note**: This will reset your location warnings for all sites and applications.